# In Teradata 16.20 is there a way to update or merge from two CTEs?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

In Teradata 16.20 is there a way to update or merge from two CTEs?

For example, in MSSQL we have a first CTE, second CTE using the first CTE, then an update:

```
with CTE1 as (
 select alpha, beta
 from someTable a
 join otherTable b on a.aleph = b.aleph
), CTE2 as (
 select beta, gamma
 from CTE1 c
 join anotherTable d on c.alpha = d.alpha
)
update u
set u.gamma = e.gamma
from updateTable u
join CTE2 e on u.beta = e.beta;
```

In Teradata 16.20 this certainly works with one CTE, like this:

```
merge into mydb.mytable
using (
 select alpha, beta
 from someTable a
 join otherTable b on a.aleph = b.aleph
) as CTE (alpha, beta)
on mytable.alpha = CTE.alpha
when matched then update
set beta = CTE.beta;
```

Is there a way to do this with **two or more** CTEs?

Comment: I don't know if I'm being overly picky, but in your Teradata query, you don't have a CTE, you have a derived table. In any case, I think Teradata only supports a single "table" as the source table (the `using` table).  You can get around that by doing all your joins and such in that derived table.

Comment: OK, I will look into alternatives, then. The manual says WITH can only be used with SELECT, so if MERGE with USING is limited to a single derived table, I am out of luck. It will not be the first time Teradata proved disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use WITH (CTE) inside a derived table (which is what you have in the `USING` clause of the `MERGE` statement above), but you can use nested derived tables:

```
merge into mydb.mytable u
using (
 select beta, gamma
 from (
   select alpha, beta
   from someTable a
   join otherTable b on a.aleph = b.aleph
 ) CTE1      
 join anotherTable d on CTE1.alpha = d.alpha
) CTE2 
on u.beta = CTE2.beta
when matched then update
set gamma = CTE2.gamma;
```

Or if `MERGE` is not applicable (e.g. join predicates don't include all the Primary Index columns) the same approach with joined `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE u FROM mydb.mytable u, 
(
 select beta, gamma
 from (
   select alpha, beta
   from someTable a
   join otherTable b on a.aleph = b.aleph
 ) CTE1      
 join anotherTable d on CTE1.alpha = d.alpha
) CTE2 
set gamma = CTE2.gamma
WHERE u.beta = CTE2.beta;
```